# Files being called with out referring them

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to ReactJs and found one example at link

```
https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/grid/
```

Click on Open in StackBlitz

In this example index.js, main.js are not linked in index.html

How come the html file uses those js files? Will HTML file works and call default js files with out adding source to the code in React applications?

Comment: Please share a proper link to the actual code and not the whole website.

Comment: there is a bundle.js connecting js files to index.html.  Here stackblitz is not showing the entire rendering html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between the files you see when you are *developing* a React application (for example: `index.html`, `index.js`, `main.js`) and the files that a browser will see once that application has been packaged up for use.

In the typical case for a React application, the application is bundled up together (often with something called [`webpack`](https://webpack.js.org/concepts)) into small packages for use by the web browser. And so, even though *your* `index.html` file does not specifically link to `index.js` or `main.js`, when you run a command like `npm start`, the bundler will take all of your code and bundle it all together, generating a page that includes all of the HTML in your `index.html` while packaging up all of your various JS code and referencing those packaged `.js` files.

This is perhaps a [helpful article](https://blog.andrewray.me/webpack-when-to-use-and-why/) that helps to explain Webpack's role in bundling up React applications, and it may help you understand why the `index.html` you see is not the same as the `index.html` that your end user will see when using your application.

---

On a separate note, because you are new to React, I would really recommend trying out an online course that walks you through the ins and outs of React. I know that everybody learns differently. I used to think that I could learn a new technology well just be reading other developer's blogs and examples; but then I realized how much more quickly and effectively I could learn a new technology by going through an online course.

I took [React - The Complete Guide, by Maximilian Schwarzmüller](https://www.udemy.com/react-the-complete-guide-incl-redux/) through Udemy. And it was excellent. Helped me a lot to understand what is going on and how to build React applications. I would highly recommend it. (By the way, I am *not* being compensated in any way for recommending this course).

Answer (score 1):

If you open the index.html page at the bottom you'll see:

```
<my-app>
     <span class="k-icon k-i-loading" style="color: #ff6358"></span>
</my-app>
```

This **my-app** here is a wrapper where all the react app is loaded.

Now if you go to **index.js**
you'll see it just loads the export of **main.js** into the module.

Finally, scroll to the bottom of **main.js** you'll see

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.querySelector('my-app')
);
```

Which means we are populating the my-app tag with App component created above in the same file.